# How to wait for element to appear

Tags: selenium, go

How can I wait for an element to appear on page using Selenium for Go?

```
import (
    "github.com/tebeka/selenium"
    "github.com/tebeka/selenium/chrome"
)

wd.Wait(selenium.Condition(Visibility))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 package main

func main(){

ops := []selenium.ServiceOption{}
    _, err := selenium.NewChromeDriverService(seleniumPath, port, ops...)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error starting the ChromeDriver server: %v", err)
    }
    
  caps := selenium.Capabilities{
        "browserName": "chrome",
    }


driver, err := selenium.NewRemote(caps, "http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

driver.WaitWithTimeoutAndInterval(bar, 1000, 1000)
}

func bar(driver selenium.WebDriver) (bool, error) {
    we, error := driver.FindElement(selenium.ByID, "idStr")
    
    return we.IsDisplayed(), error

}
```